# How to get my .toggleClass() menu to work properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently constructing a menu that consists of 2 hyperlinks, "Sign In" and "Sign Up". My goal is to have this menu work in such a way that when either hyperlink is clicked on, the appropriate div will appear below. For example, the user clicks on "Sign Up", then the "Sign up" form appears below. I have no issues with these `<div>`'s appearing, I have made a functioning script that uses the `.slideToggle()` function. Before I go any further, please view my website on a device with a screen size of 1400px or more, and click on both the "Sign Up" and "Sign In" hyperlinks. (http://www.codesrce.com)

If you noticed when you click on "Sign Up" or "Sign In", for the first click on each the text turns a greenish color, and then when you click on the other, it reverts back to white, and the one you most recently clicked on turns green. The problem is, what I am looking for is not working. It works for a brief moment, then gets messed up when you click them more than  3 times. Here is my question:

How can I make this menu work in a way that when either "Sign Up" or "Sign In" is clicked on, it changes the font color, but also when that same link is clicked again, or another the other link is clicked on, it reverts back to its original color, leaving that newly clicked link with a new text color until that one is clicked again or the other link is clicked on? I hope I am making sense. I will provide my code so far, and hopefully someone can help me out!

Basicaly, If one hyperlink is active with the greenish color, then the other one should be non-active with the white font color, and if neither one is active, then have both be white.

### **Colors**

Greenish: `#4AE6AB`

White: (Obviously) `#fff` or `white`

### **Code**

HTML:

```
<div id="BottomTop">
   <div id="UserMenuBar">
      <a class="ToggleSignInForm">Sign In</a><a class="ToggleSignUpForm">Sign Up</a>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="SignInFormToggled" id="SignInForm">
   <form id="signinform" onsubmit="return false;">
   </form>
</div>
<div class="SignUpFormToggled" id="SignUpForm">
   <form name="signupform" id="signupform" onsubmit="return false;">
   </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#SignInForm {
    background: rgb(154,234,204);
    height: 120px;
}

#SignUpForm {
    background: rgb(154,234,204);
    height: 120px;
}

.SignInFormToggled {
    display: none;
}

.SignUpFormToggled {
    display: none;
}

.ForgotPasswordFormToggled {
    display: none;
}

#BottomTop {
    background: #333333;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}

#UserMenuBar {
    background: #333333;
    /* Old browsers */
    height: 40px;
    width: 1400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-family: 'Gotham Rounded Book', Myraid Pro, Segoe UI, Helvetica Neue, Arial;
}

#UserMenuBar a {
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: color 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: color 0.3s ease;
    transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

#UserMenuBar a:hover {
    color: #4AE6AB;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#UserMenuBar a.active {
    color: #4AE6AB;
}

#UserMenuBar a.notactive {
    color: #fff;
}

#SignInFormContainer {
    width: 1400px;
    height: 120px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#SignUpFormContainer {
    width: 1400px;
    height: 120px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $('.ToggleSignInForm').click(function () {
        $('.SignInFormToggled').slideToggle();
        $('.SignUpFormToggled').css("display", "none");
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        if ($('.ToggleSignUpForm').hasClass('active')) {
            $('.ToggleSignUpForm').toggleClass('notactive');
        } else {}
    });
});

$(function () {
    $('.ToggleSignUpForm').click(function () {
        $('.SignUpFormToggled').slideToggle();
        $('.SignInFormToggled').css("display", "none");
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        if ($('.ToggleSignInForm').hasClass('active')) {
            $('.ToggleSignInForm').toggleClass('notactive');
        } else {}
    });
});

$(function () {
    $('.ToggleForgotPasswordForm').click(function () {
        $('.ForgotPasswordFormToggled').slideToggle();

    });
});
```

Comment: Your divs are mismatched...You've got too many closing tags...

Comment: Whoops! Thanks for catching that. The code I provided here is just a small snippet required for the menu to work. They are needed in the full code, and have no affect on the JQuery @mattingly890

Comment: You only need one DOM ready function, not 3.

Comment: It doesn't work with only one @tymeJV

Comment: @user3761911 -- It's not the fix to your problem, just a suggestion - you dont need to wrap every event it is own DOM ready function.

Comment: Yeah I apologize for my stupidity, as this does work with only one DOM ready function. I had left out a closing bracket, which is why it did not work. :) @tymeJV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer. Javascript is weird sometimes, but this code works!

Thank you @imbondbaby and others for leading me in the right direction.

JS:

```
$(function () {
$('.ToggleSignInForm').click(function () {
    $('.SignInFormToggled').slideToggle();
    $('.SignUpFormToggled').css("display", "none");
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    if ($('.ToggleSignUpForm').hasClass('active')) {
        $('.ToggleSignUpForm').toggleClass('notactive');
        $('.ToggleSignUpForm').toggleClass('active');
    }
    if ($('.ToggleSignUpForm').hasClass('notactive')) {
        $('.ToggleSignUpForm').toggleClass('active');
    }

    if ($('.ToggleSignUpForm').hasClass('notactive')) {
        $('.ToggleSignUpForm').toggleClass('active');
        $('.ToggleSignUpForm').toggleClass('notactive');
    }
   if ($('.ToggleSignUpForm').hasClass('active')) {
        $('.ToggleSignUpForm').toggleClass('notactive');
    }
});
$('.ToggleSignUpForm').click(function () {
    $('.SignUpFormToggled').slideToggle();
    $('.SignInFormToggled').css("display", "none");
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    if ($('.ToggleSignInForm').hasClass('active')) {
        $('.ToggleSignInForm').toggleClass('notactive');
        $('.ToggleSignInForm').toggleClass('active');
    }
    if ($('.ToggleSignInForm').hasClass('notactive')) {
        $('.ToggleSignInForm').toggleClass('active');
    }

    if ($('.ToggleSignInForm').hasClass('notactive')) {
        $('.ToggleSignInForm').toggleClass('active');
        $('.ToggleSignInForm').toggleClass('notactive');
    }
    if ($('.ToggleSignInForm').hasClass('active')) {
        $('.ToggleSignInForm').toggleClass('notactive');
    }
});

});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0p7zghdj/5/)**

Answer (score 1):

## **Code Cleanup:**

Your `div`'s are mismatched. You have more closing tags for `div` than opening tags.

Also, you can get rid of the `else` statement if it is blank. You don't have to have an `else` statement if it is not needed.

You have three DOM `document.ready` functions but you just need one.

## **Solution:**

Change:

```
$('.ToggleSignUpForm').toggleClass('notactive');
```

To:

```
$('.ToggleSignInForm').toggleClass('notactive');
$('.ToggleSignInForm').toggleClass('active');
```

## **UPDATE**

Add:

```
$('.active').removeClass('active');
```

Before:

```
$(this).toggleClass('active');
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0p7zghdj/4/)**

Comment: That does work for half of what I am looking for. When one link is active, the other is not. But when neither links are clicked, meaning that neither the Sign Up of Sign In forms are displaying, unless the page has just been loaded, the last clicked link is still colored green. I want both to be colored white when there is no form open at all. @imbondbaby

Comment: That works for the first 3 clicks when you go back and forth from sign up to sign in, the it stops working. Weird @imbondbaby

Comment: Haha I just found a solution right before I read this. However, yours is much shorter, and you took the time to help me so thank you very much! @imbondbaby

Comment: OMG. The only thing that doesn't work on yours is the reverting the color back to white when not active. I will post a solution. Still thank you for leading me in the right direction @imbondbaby

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the classes. In css, the last listed class overrides all previous classes for the elements involved. After you click a few times, the `notactive` class ends up at the end and overrides the `active` class. To solve this, simply toggle the `active` class when you toggle the `notactive` class. This makes sure only one of these classes is implemented at any given time, and will solve the problem.

The JS will look like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('.ToggleSignInForm').click(function () {
        $('.SignInFormToggled').slideToggle();
        $('.SignUpFormToggled').css("display", "none");
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        if ($('.ToggleSignUpForm').hasClass('active')) {
            $('.ToggleSignUpForm').removeClass('active').addClass('notactive');
        } else {}
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
    });
});

$(function () {
    $('.ToggleSignUpForm').click(function () {
        $('.SignUpFormToggled').slideToggle();
        $('.SignInFormToggled').css("display", "none");
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        if ($('.ToggleSignInForm').hasClass('active')) {
            $('.ToggleSignInForm').removeClass('active').addClass('notactive');
        } else {}
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: It works for the first few clicks, but it still doesn't work continuously. If you go back and forth from sign in to sign up it will eventually stop working and get messed up. @RamsaySmith

Comment: Okay. I removed your implementation of `toggleClass` and put `removeClass` and `addClass` instead. Does that work?